# how to get the number of columns that have the same value between 2 rows

Tags: python, deep-learning, pandas

I want to compare two records and get the number of columns that have the same value , for example
I have two rows, the first row is :

| rank | rank1 | rank2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |

and the second row is

| rank | rank1 | rank2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

the result should be 2 columns have the same value. is there a function in python that is capable of performing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If your records are in form of a pandas dataframe, then you can use `df.columns.duplicated()` to know the columns which are duplicated.

Comment: this is if they are in the same data frame but if it is separated as shown in the example above can we still use it